# Eclipse : key on Android AES encryption and decryption

Tags: java, android, eclipse, encryption, aes

I just want to ask.

I have SMS application with AES encryption for android on eclipse, but I had a problem.

The problem is when I put the key in less than 16 characters, the message can not be encrypted. but if the key is 16 characters, the message can be encrypted.

I want to insert the key, regardless of the amount. The key can be generated to 16 characters, to get 128 bit. So, how the code is supposed to solve that problem?

Thanks in advance - I hope you can help me.

```
public class AES {
    public static String encrypt(String message, String key){
        try {
            SecretKeySpec KS = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, KS);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());      
            return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.NO_PADDING);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             return "ERROR:"+e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static String decrypt(String chiperText, String key){
        try {

            SecretKeySpec KS = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, KS);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(chiperText, Base64.NO_PADDING));
            return new String(decrypted);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             return "ERROR";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is insecure because you use a password as key directly via `password.getBytes()`.

**NEVER EVER DO THIS!**

Use a proper key derivation function like PBKDF2 which generates the key based on the password. The same password together with the same PBKDF2 parameters will end up in the same key.

For more details please read for example this blog post: [Using Password-based Encryption on Android](http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2012/04/using-password-based-encryption-on.html).

Comment: i solved my key code problem.
I try to run applications on AVD without Google API, all the functions work well.
but, if I run app on AVD with Google API or install on android phone. encrypted text can't decrypt properly.
how to fix the problem?

Comment: The GoogleAPI has no impact on AES encryption/decryption. May be the used Android version has an impact on code party you did not post. The next time you should post a fully working example including sample encrypted/decrypted data and keys.

Comment: thank you for all your answers.
the problem only on compatibility. :D